# Amazon QuickSight embedded dashboard is too slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, dashboard, amazon-quicksight

I have embedded Amazon QuickSight dashboard in my web application by using [amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk).
But the problem assets in iframe is very heavy and it's very slow.
I need to wait for 2 mins to get this loaded.
And since embedded URL has been changed every time, it is not cached.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the dashboard on its own (not embedded) load equally slow? If so - do you use Spice of query underlying data directly? Spice can significantly speed things up.

Comment: I am using spice and it is faster in quicksight.